# Do IMAX screens in America play non-IMAX movies?

Tags: film-techniques, imax

In India, I am very sure non-IMAX movies are played in IMAX screens. I am not sure whether American IMAX screens plays them. My friend says they "should not" play non-IMAX movies in IMAX screens in America.

**Is it true?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMAX is a brand name. It appears that many cinemas across the world are gearing up to show films on *larger-than-average* screens under the IMAX banner, without these actually being *IMAX-quality* films.

There's an article about it [here](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20090513/0150344862.shtml) relating to AMC's tie-up with IMAX and showing the difference between a 'classic' IMAX screen and an AMC IMAX screen (see below)

Conversely, most IMAX cinemas in the UK and US regularly run screenings of classic non-IMAX films on their IMAX screens. I myself went to see Akira on an IMAX screen in Birmingham, presumably it had been upscaled to fit the screen without distortion.

[image]

Comment: For the record, Akira was awesome on the big big big screen.